# UITableViewCell Not Sizing To UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was wondering if anyone knows hot to fix this issue. When I run the app, the image gets cut off instead of displayed. I have attached photos to show in detail.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights It doesn't look like you have any constraints. You may just have to set constraints on the image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two kind of Cells in the Table View, you have to set the height of both cells programatically inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Currently, you have only one cell size and I think it is default to `44.0`.

Comment: I was able to solve it already by doing what you said. It stinks Xcode can't use storyboard to know the height when working with more then one cell.

Answer (score 0):

May be you doesn't set imageview's constraints properly.

Set top, bottom, left, rignt constraint of imageview with tableviewcell frame properly. Give a aspect ratio size of the imageview.
And return **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate functions. 
This will work !!